# Ubuntu Core 20.4 can't ping Opto22 Snap Pac Brain

Tags: networking, iptables, ubuntu-core

I'm working on a Raspberry Py 4 with the lastest Ubuntu Core 20.4 64bits.

I need to be able to reach and use a device, the Opto22 Snap Pac Brain Model SNAP-PAC-EB2. This device is linked to the raspberry with an ethernet cable.

The Brain is fully functionnal. It works on unbutu desktop and window 10, it's recognized and usable, so the problems comes from the ubuntu core.

I tried to open all ports with :

```
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

with no success...

[Current state I get from iptables -L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw7tk.png)

My question is : **How can I ping and use my Snap-pac-brain starting from a freshly installed Ubuntu Core 20.4 ?**

Link to the device I use : https://www.opto22.com/products/snap-pac-eb2

EDIT :
Here's the ping command and their output

[Ping command on window, I'm using an usb 3.0 to rj45 (ethernet) adaptator to connect the brain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy2AF.png)

[Ping command on the raspberry. I'm connect through ssh (mandatory with ubuntu core) from my window machine. The first command is without the usb/rj45 adaptor, the second is with it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsnUr.png)

I didn't change anything from my question. All the ports are still open. I would be the same result if I closed them anyway. This is basically a fresh ubuntu core installation.

Edit 2 :

[pi machine ifconfig (with the opto linked)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OJKA.png)

[ipconfig on my windows pc with opto linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GghJl.png)

[pac manager of my opto22 brain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjfPi.png)

Comment: Your output seems to show that your firewall (iptables) is not the issue: All packets accepted, which is the default for a new install of Ubuntu. If you want help with pinging, show us some ping input and output.

Comment: I added to the main post the pictures showing the ping commands. I don't think they are very useful though. If nothing can be concluded, I can re-install ubuntu core and show all the steps starting from the choice of the OS.

Comment: Your output suggests that your Pi and Opto22 are on different subnets. If they are indeed on the same subnet, check for an IP address collision.

Comment: I checked (see edit2), they seem to be on different subnets. Also, the pi seems to not recognize when my opto22 is linked on it. I don't understand what to do now...